# Error: absolute path: //fileName/ unzipping a folder in protractor nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I tried many ways available in different sites to unzip the downloaded zipped folder and found the below one is simplest way.However, am facing the below issue.Please help me resolve this :

```
const extract = require('extract-zip');

const path = require('path');

unzip=async function(){
        let source = "Downloads/sample.zip";
        let destination = "Downloads/";
            let sP = path.resolve(source);
            console.log("Source path : " +sP);
            let dP = path.resolve(destination);
            console.log("Destination path : " +dP);
            await extract(sP, { dir: dP });
            console.log('Extraction complete');

        }
```

Output :

```
Source path : /Users/myName/Documents/framework/Downloads/sample.zip
Destination path :/Users/myName/Documents/framework/Downloads
.
.
Error: absolute path://sample/
```

Answer (score 2):

The resolved path should be relative to the path of the directory where the code is being executed.

Replace

`let source = '../../Downloads/sample.zip`

`let destination = '../../Downloads`

`let sP = path.resolve(source);`

`let dP = path.resolve(destination);`

Comment: it is trying to find the zip file in the folder where this .js file is residing(ex : /Users/myName/Documents/framework/com/cmpny/abc/xyz/pageObjects/Downloads/sample.zip)  . But my downloaded file resides in project root folder i.e,/Users/myName/Documents/framework/Downloads/ folder...... Any help on this.

Comment: You need to specify the `source`and `destination`path relative to your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the .zip file itself starting with //.  Extract-zip uses yauzl which throws an exception if it's an absolute path:
https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl/issues/135